# JSON dictionary error

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I read my json file and set a string variable,i'm using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

```
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("odul_en.json"),FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
    string jsonGelen = sr.ReadToEnd();
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var dict = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonGelen);
```

When i put breakpoint  "var dict= serializer.Deserialize>(jsonGelen);" rows,  I am getting the below error;

> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'

odul_en.json like this;

```
 [{
"odulID": "130",
"Ad": "LaQ Creative Toy / Basic 001",
"Aciklama": "Instead of the gift product, the product is not paid for the price, can not be turned into money. There is no guarantee of the products because of collective purchase. Buying gift product is not returned. Photos are representative, products may vary."},{
"odulID": "132",
"Ad": "Selfie Stick",
"Aciklama": "Instead of the gift product, the product is not paid for the price, can not be turned into money. There is no guarantee of the products because of collective purchase. Photos are representative, products may vary. Buying gift product is not returned. There is no color option. Suitable for Phones, easy to carry. The open length is 100 cm and the closed length is 23 cm"}]
```

I searched solution way; someone said "remove the square brackets" at json file but not solved.
(My .net framework 3.5 and can't use dynamics)
How can i solved this, thank you.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: are you sure that's the whole error? Is there some kind of inner exception? Have you tried using JSON.NET instead of the now-outdated JavascriptSerialiser class?

Comment: @ADyson, our web server does not support newtonsoft. I had to use System.Web.Script.Serialization library :(

Comment: It's something you have to download first. It supports .NET 3.5, there should be no reason why you can't use it. You just include it in your project via Nuget or via including the DLL manually. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Comment: @ADyson, I tried newtonsoft.json but didn't word.

Comment: "didn't work" doesn't mean much to me. What precisely did you try? What precisely went wrong? Can't really help you if you don't explain the problem :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, looking more closely at the JSON, I don't see how it could ever work. What are you expecting to be placed into the "string" key of each entry in the dictionary? Since your JSON is an array, it doesn't have a named key for each entry. If you try to de-serialise it using JSON.NET the exception message informs you that deserialising to this kind of dictionary structure requires the JSON to be an object (with named keys), not an array.

You'd be better off deserialising to a list of a custom type which contains properties matching the fields in your JSON. Here's an example, again using JSON.NET (also known as Newtonsoft.JSON):

Model class:

```
public class Product
{
  public int odulID { get; set; }
  public string Ad { get; set; }
  public string Aciklama { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialisation code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("odul_en.json"),FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);           
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
string jsonGelen = sr.ReadToEnd();
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(jsonGelen);
```

Comment: Thanks ADyson, i solved problem with newtonsoft.json nugget. I must develop my English and json logic :)) See you another problems :)

Comment: @HakanSerbest I'm pleased that you resolved your issue. If this answer helped you solve the problem then please remember to mark it as "accepted", thankyou

Answer (score -1):

odul_en.json is json array, fix like this:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("odul_en.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
string jsonGelen = sr.ReadToEnd();
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = serializer.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(jsonGelen);
```